# undefined method error Find_by when trying to add Custom Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Edit** It seems that this error is only getting thrown when 1. I add a custom domain and try to point it to my cname and 2. when I'm in development and on the root directory.

**Edit 2** per the recommendation to at the class name to find_by I've updated the appliction controller to have Page.find_by

Now I'm getting this error

[image]

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160314190349) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "custom_domains", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "value"
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "custom_domains", ["page_id"], name: "index_custom_domains_on_page_id", using: :btree

  create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "headline"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "buttoncolor"
    t.string   "buttontext"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "main_referral_page_id"
    t.integer  "page_owner_referral_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.string   "subheadline"
    t.string   "subdomain"
    t.string   "ga_tracking_id"
    t.string   "mailchimp_list_name"
  end

  create_table "pages_subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "referral_count"
    t.integer  "referral_page_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "subscriber_id"
    t.integer  "page_id"
  end

  add_index "pages_subscribers", ["referral_page_id"], name: "index_pages_subscribers_on_referral_page_id", using: :btree
  add_index "pages_subscribers", ["user_id"], name: "index_pages_subscribers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "referral_pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "navcolor"
    t.string   "rheadline"
    t.string   "rheadlinecolor"
    t.string   "rbackgroundcolor"
    t.string   "rboxcolor"
    t.string   "rcountcolor"
    t.string   "rhow"
    t.string   "rhowcolor"
    t.string   "rightheadline"
    t.string   "rightsub"
    t.string   "rightcolor"
    t.string   "bottomsub"
    t.string   "buynow"
    t.string   "buylink"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "twitter"
    t.string   "facebook"
  end

  create_table "rewards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "level"
    t.float    "discount"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.integer  "referral_page_id"
    t.integer  "referral_count_required"
    t.integer  "page_id"
  end

  add_index "rewards", ["page_id"], name: "index_rewards_on_page_id", using: :btree

  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "reference_count"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  add_index "subscribers", ["page_id"], name: "index_subscribers_on_page_id", using: :btree
  add_index "subscribers", ["user_id"], name: "index_subscribers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "reference_count",        default: 0,  null: false
    t.string   "role"
    t.string   "mailchimp_api_key"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "custom_domains", "pages"
  add_foreign_key "rewards", "pages"
  add_foreign_key "subscribers", "pages"
  add_foreign_key "subscribers", "users"
end
```

For example if I navigate to localhost300/user/sign_in I can log in and use the app.

Adding my routes file below.

I'm getting a strange error and can't seem to find an answer.

I've set up my controller to allow my app to accept custom domains. I've read around that this can be caused by using older versions of rails but I believe I'm upto date.

I'm running:

Rails 4.2.6

and

ruby 2.2.2p95

The error is happening in the set_page method in my application controller.

This method is called in my pages_controller so the error message shows it happening there but that method is actually stored in the applicaton controller.

Here is the error message

[image: Error message]

Application_Controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include Pundit
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_authorized, unless: :devise_controller?  or :subscribers_controller?

  def home
  end

  def set_page
    # lookup domain and compage to actionpages.co env var
    if request.domain == ENV['APP_DOMAIN'] # actionpages.co
    #  look for a subdomain to exist
     if request.subdomain.present? && !request.subdomain.downcase.include?("www")
      @page = Page.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
     end
    else
      # this is a custom domain look up the page for the custom domain
      @page = Page.find_by(custom_domain: request.domain)
      not_found unless @page.present?
    end
    authorize @page unless @page.nil?
  end

  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :mailchimp_api_key, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

  helper_method :subscriber_logged_in?
  def subscriber_logged_in?
    if cookies["subscriber_id"]
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
  end

  helper_method :share_id_for_subscriber_and_page
  def share_id_for_subscriber_and_page(subscriber, page)
    PagesSubscriber.share_id_for_subscriber_and_page(subscriber, page)
  end

end
```

Pages_controller.rb

```
# require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'csv'
require 'rails/all'

class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  layout "page", only: [:show]

  def index
    if current_user
      @pages = current_user.pages
      authorize @pages
    else
      set_page
      if @page.nil?
        # monster hack here, needs removed and better controller direction
        # for the root contoller. Passthrough options needed.
        authorize Page.new
        render 'static/home'
      else
        render 'pages/show.html.erb' unless current_user
      end
    end
  end

  def show
     @page ||= current_user.pages.find(params[:id])
     @referral_page = @page.referral_page
     @referrer_id = params[:referrer_id]
     @rewards = @page.rewards
     authorize @page
  end

  def new
    @page = current_user.pages.create(default)
    authorize @page

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def create
    authorize @page
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @page ||= current_user.pages.find(params[:id])
    authorize @page

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.update(page_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @page ||= current_user.pages.find(params[:id])
    authorize @page

    @page.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pages_url, notice: 'Page was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def downloadCSV
    @subscribers = Page.find(csv_params[:id]).subscribers
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data @subscribers.to_csv }
    end
    authorize Page
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    # def set_page
    #   @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    #   authorize @page
    # end
    #
    # def set_page(page = nil) # set page, optional page paramater for subdomains
    #   @page = page ? page : params[:id] ? Page.find(params[:id]) : Page.first
    #   @referral_page = @page.referral_page
    #   @referrer_id = params[:referrer_id]
    #   @rewards = @page.rewards
    #   authorize @page
    # end

    def default
      {
        :subdomain => Page.unique_subdomain,
        :headline => "Hover Over Any Element To See The Edit Button",
        :subheadline => "You can change the image, button color, button text, and the headline.",
        :color => "White",
        :buttoncolor => "warning",
        :buttontext => "Button Text",
        :image => nil,
        :user_id => current_user
      }
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:headline,
        :subheadline,
        :color,
        :buttoncolor,
        :buttontext,
        :image,
        :user_id,
        :subdomain,
        :ga_tracking_id,
        :mailchimp_list_name,
        custom_domains_attributes: [:id, :value, :_destroy])
    end

    def csv_params
      params.permit(:id)
    end

end


Routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'referrals/show'

  get 'test' => 'users#test_mailchimp'

  devise_for :users

  resources :rewards
  resources :subscribers
  resources :users
  get 'mailchimp' => 'users#mailchimp'
  post 'mailchimp' => 'users#update_mailchimp'

  resources :pages do
    resources :referral_pages do
    end
  end

  # Custom Routing
  get 'pages/:id/downloadCSV' => 'pages#downloadCSV', defaults: { format: 'csv' }
  get 'pages/:page_id/create_referral_page' => 'referral_pages#create_with_defaults'
  get 'pages/:id/:referrer_id' => 'pages#show'


  get "about" => "static#about"
  get "pricing" => "static#pricing"

  get 'refer/(:referrer_id)' => 'referrals#show', as: 'refer'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'pages#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

I've been stuck on this error all night! Any ideas?

Comment: Add the class name to the method call for ActiveRecord queries.  `Page.find_by...`

Comment: @JoeEssey I edited the question. I'm getting a new error now.

Comment: Hi, I understand that you want to get your app up and running but please try to ask one question at a time. Constantly changing the scope of your question kills the quality and is disrespectful to anbody who has answered the question. Your first error was due a simple typographical error. The second is most likely that you have not run the migration or even created a migration to add the correct database column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `Page`:

```
def set_page
  # lookup domain and compage to actionpages.co env var
  if request.domain == ENV['APP_DOMAIN'] # actionpages.co
  #  look for a subdomain to exist
   if request.subdomain.present? && !request.subdomain.downcase.include?("www")
    @page = Page.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
   end
  else
    # this is a custom domain look up the page for the custom domain
    #       vvvv MISSING THE Page HERE
    @page = Page.find_by(custom_domain: request.domain)
    not_found unless @page.present?
  end
  authorize @page unless @page.nil?
end
```

However, as per your new error, you don't have a `custom_domain` field in your `pages` table.

Check your `schema.rb` and in case you need to add this field create a migration for that.

EDIT: you have a `custom_domains` table associated to `pages`, so you need something like:

```
def set_page
  # lookup domain and compage to actionpages.co env var
  if request.domain == ENV['APP_DOMAIN'] # actionpages.co
  #  look for a subdomain to exist
   if request.subdomain.present? && !request.subdomain.downcase.include?("www")
    @page = Page.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
   end
  else
    # this is a custom domain look up the page for the custom domain
    custom_domain = CustomDomain.find_by(value: request.domain)
    @page = custom_domain.page if custom_domain
    not_found unless @page.present?
  end
  authorize @page unless @page.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just updated the question to include my schema. I have a custome_domains table and have a CustomDomain model.

Comment: you have a custom_domains table and not an attribute in pages. Please note my edited answer

Comment: thanks for editing the notes, I'm now getting a route error route not found

Comment: I marked this correct as I think it solved my first two bugs. I'll move this to another question.